# When is $\infty$ a critical point of a rational function on the sphere?

Tags: rational-functions, riemann-sphere

In his "Iteration of Rational Functions" Beardon [defines a critical point](http://books.google.com/books?id=wAhFqe0AWRQC&lpg=PA43&vq=critical%20point&pg=PA43#v=onepage&q&f=false) of a rational function (mapping the Riemann sphere to itself) as a point such that the function is not injective in any neighborhood of that point.

I'm trying to square Beardon's definition with the [other definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_%28mathematics%29), in which a critical point is a point at which the function is either not differentiable or the derivative is zero.  Specifically, I'm trying to determine when/if/how I can use the second definition to evaluate whether or not $\infty$ is a critical point.

> When is $\infty$ a critical point of a rational function mapping the Riemann sphere to itself?

A rule like, "a point $z\in\mathbb{C}$ is critical if $f'(z) = 0$ or $\infty$, and $\infty$ is critical if $1/f'(\infty) = 0$ or $\infty$," would fit nicely with Beardon's [classification of fixed (and later periodic) points by multiplier](http://books.google.ca/books?id=wAhFqe0AWRQC&lpg=PP1&vq=multipler&pg=PA40#v=onepage&q&f=false).  But I haven't been able to find this rule for critical points stated explicitly in Beardon or anywhere else.

**Edit:** Thinking about this a little more, I think the rule might be

> Infinity is a critical point of $f$ if and only if zero is a critical point of $1/f$.

An argument goes: The valency of $f$ at any point is invariant under conjugation by a Möbius transformation, so instead of considering the valency of $f$ at $\infty$ we can consider the valency of the conjugate $g:z\to 1/f(1/z)$ at $\infty$.  Now

$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(1/f(1/z))(\infty) &= \lim_{a\to\infty}{\frac{\partial}{\partial z}}(1/f(1/z))(a)\\ &= \lim_{a\to 0}{\frac{\partial}{\partial z}}(1/f(z))(a)\\ &= \frac{\partial}{\partial z}(1/f(z))(0)
\end{aligned}$.

And the second step there is supposed to be justified by the fact that everything in sight is continuous (though I'm afraid I might be forgetting some basic calculus gotcha).  Anyway, *assuming* that the above steps are correct and *assuming* that knowledge of the derivative is all that's needed to determine the valency, then that should do it: The valency of $f$ at $\infty$ is the same as the valency of $1/f$ at zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just choose an appropriate pair of charts. Write $f(z) = p(z) / q(z)$, where $p$ and $q$ are polynomial functions with no common zeros. We may assume $f$ is not a constant function – the constant case is trivial. There are a few cases:

- $f(\infty) = \infty$ – look at the function $w \mapsto \frac{1}{f(1 / w)}$. The derivative is given by
  $$\frac{f' (1/w)}{w^2 f(1/w)^2} = \frac{p'(1/w) q(1/w) - p(1/w) q'(1/w)}{w^2 p(1/w)^2}$$
  but it's not immediate how to extract anything useful from this expression. Instead, suppose the leading term of $p(z)$ is $a z^n$ while the leading term of $q(z)$ is $b z^m$. We must have $n > m$ if $f(\infty) = \infty$, and the numerator is of degree $n + m - 1$ (in terms of $1/w$) and the denominator is of degree $2 n - 2$. Now there are two subcases:

  - $m = n - 1$ – then the value of the expression at $w = 0$ is $\frac{b}{a}$; in particular, $\infty$ is not a critical point of $f$.
  - $m < n - 1$ – then the value of the expression at $w = 0$ is $0$, so $\infty$ is a critical point of $f$.
- $f(\infty) \ne \infty$ – look at the function $w \mapsto f(1 / w)$. The derivative is given by 
  $$-\frac{f' (1/w)}{w^2} = -\frac{p'(1/w) q(1/w) - p(1/w) q'(1/w)}{w^2 q(1/w)^2}$$
  but again it's not clear what we can say from this. Let $a z^n$ be the leading term of $p(z)$ and let $b z^m$ be the leading term of $q(z)$. We must have $n \le m$ if $f(\infty) \ne \infty$, and the numerator is of degree $n + m - 1$ (if $n \ne m$) or $< n + m - 1$ (if $n = m$) and the denominator is of degree $2 m - 2$. Now there are four subcases:

  - $n = m = 1$ – then $f$ is a Möbius transformation and the value of the expression is non-zero; in particular, $\infty$ is not a critical point of $f$.
  - $n = m > 1$ – if the numerator is of degree $2 m - 2$ as well, then the value of the expression is non-zero; if the numerator is of degree $< 2 m - 2$, then the value of the expression is zero. (Both sub-subcases are possible, of course.)
  - $n = m - 1$ – then the value of the expression at $w = 0$ is $-\frac{a}{b}$; in particular, $\infty$ is not a critical point of $f$.
  - $n < m - 1$ – then the value of the expression at $w = 0$ is $0$, so $\infty$ is a critical point of $f$.

At any rate, the point is that there is no *easy* criterion purely in terms of the values of $f$ and $f'$.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not understanding why we can't use the $w\to1/f(1/w)$ function even when $f(\infty)\neq\infty$.  If we do that everything works out the same in your first two cases, but we have an additional possibility: $m > n - 1$.  In that case the expression is equal to $\infty$ at $w=0$, and $\infty$ is a critical point of $f$, right?

As for your $f(\infty)\neq\infty$ case, I'm not sure that we can get much from considering $w\to f(1/w)$ because that function isn't conjugate to $f$.  Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: You can use either function if $f(\infty) \notin \{ 0, \infty \}$.

Comment: I guess what I'm not understanding is why we *can't* use the first function, $w:1/f(1/w)$, when $f(\infty) = 0$.  Then $m > n$, the degree of $p'(1/w)q(1/w) - p(1/w)q'(1/w)$ (in terms of $1/w$) is $n + m - 1$, and the degree of the denominator is still $2n - 2$, but since $m > n - 1$, $\frac{f'(1/w)}{w^2 f(1/w)^2}$ has a pole at $w = 0$, and $\infty$ is a critical point of $f$.

Comment: That's obviously not correct. The function $z \mapsto \frac{1}{z}$ vanishes at $\infty$, but $\infty$ is not a critical point.

Comment: Opps, I guess I never said it explicitly, but we don't have to think much when the degree of $f$ is less than two, as such functions have no critical points in $\mathbb{C}_\infty$.  If we restrict our attention to rational functions of degree at least two, do we still need your $w\to f(1/w)$ case?

Comment: The function $z \mapsto \frac{z}{z^2 - 1}$ vanishes at $\infty$, but $\infty$ is not a critical point. It is simply not true that the derivative blowing up at $w = 0$ implies that there is a critical point at $w = 0$.

Comment: OK, that was my biggest misunderstanding, thinking that if the derivative had a pole then that indicated a critical point.  Thank you so much for the thorough explanation.

Comment: Just to be clear, was "Infinity is a critical point of f if and only if zero is a critical point of 1/f". true?